# How can I backup Github bugtracker?

Tags: github, backup, bug-tracker

How can I easily backup & restore bugtracker of project on Github? Repository itself is obvious, wiki is also a git repository - but what about bugtracker?

I want to fully backup bugtracker (tickets, attached imaged, labels, comments, images attached in comments, dates of creation and closing of tickets etc) with ability to recreate it on github account.

Saving it as editable format would be a good bonus.

I am aware about Github API and that I can make tool like this. But I would prefer to use (optionally improve) existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Existing ones mainly export the issue text, not always their attachments.

- [github-issues-export](https://github.com/colmsjo/github-issues-export)
- [github-to-bitbucket-issues-migration](https://github.com/sorich87/github-to-bitbucket-issues-migration)

Those services could be extended [with the issue API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) to export more.

A more complete service is **[backhub.co](https://backhub.co/)**, which [exports a bit more](https://backhub.co/faq.html) (but isn't as easily expendable). It is free for public repos.

---

Update August 2018: [vorburger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421602/vorburger) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834097/how-can-i-backup-github-bugtracker/23842150?noredirect=1#comment91247003_23842150) a direct link example of how to use the GitHub Issues API to obtain all comments from a particular issue:

https://api.github.com/repos/JDKMissionControl/jmc/issues/1/comments

Comment: Here is a direct link example of how to use the GitHub Issues API to obtain all comments from a particular issue: https://api.github.com/repos/JDKMissionControl/jmc/issues/1/comments

Comment: @vorburger Thank you. I have included your comment in the answers for more visibility.